# background images are not working properly

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to develop a website with custom backgrounds. But the backgrounds don't work.

Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom background</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://goo.gl/b8xuMH">

</head>
<body>
<script>
    var a = prompt("What Do You Like (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List To Show List)");
    if (a === "List") {
        confirm("Cars,");
        var a = prompt("What Do You Like (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List To Show List)");
    }

    if (a === "Cars") {
        var b = prompt("What Type (Capitalize All Words) (Type In “List” To Show List)");
    } else {
        confirm("did not understand");
    }

    if (b === "List") {
        confirm("Sports Cars,");
        var b = prompt("What Type (Capitalize All Words) (Type In “List” To Show List)");
    }

    if (b === "Sports Cars") {
        var c = prompt("What  Company (Capitalize All Words)(Type In List To Show List)");
    } else {
        confirm("did not understand");
    }

    if (c === "List") {
        confirm("Bocar,");
        var c = prompt("What U.S.A. Company (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List To Show List)");
    }

    if (c === "Bocar") {
        var d = prompt("What Model (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List To Show List)");
    }

    if (d === "List") {
        confirm("Stiletto,");
        var d = prompt("What Model (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List To Show List)");
    }

    if (d === "Stiletto, Xp-4") {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://goo.gl/l8Pjl8')";
    } else if (d === "Xp-4") {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://goo.gl/CEHZ4N')";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Guide me to fix this.

Comment: <img rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" src="https://goo.gl/b8xuMH">

Comment: It does work. I entered in all expected input and the background changed.

Comment: Worked for me.  For the last prompt - are you entering "Stiletto, Xp-4" in the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Your last if and else if block's conditions are never met.  I suggest editing those conditions and adding and `else` statement so if none of the conditions are met it will show at least some other image

```
if (d === "Stiletto, Xp-4") {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://goo.gl/l8Pjl8')";
} else if (d === "Xp-4") {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://goo.gl/CEHZ4N')";
} else if (d === "Stiletto") {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url('some other image')";
} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url('if no other conditions are met use this')";
}
```

Comment: Stiletto, Xp4 is the choices we have

Comment: Could you elaborate?  Because if the user is to input "Stiletto, Xp-4" then the background does change without a problem